# ASP.NET MVC 2 controller not cached

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, caching, controller, renderaction

I have amaster page that calls render action:

```
<% Html.RenderAction("CategoryList", "Category", new { selectedCategoryId = Model.selectedCategoryId });  %>
```

and the action looks like:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
[OutputCache(Duration = 10, VaryByParam = "none")]
public ActionResult CategoryList(int? selectedCategoryId)
{

    CategoryList cl = CategoryManager.GetList();
    if (selectedCategoryId.HasValue)
        CategoryManager.SetSelectedCategory(cl, selectedCategoryId.Value);
    return PartialView(cl);
}
```

But when i run SQL profiler i see that the GetList() query is always called, meaning the action is not being cached.

Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's a child action meaning that it is only a part of the final HTML and cannot be cached. For caching fragments of your HTML checkout [this blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/05/donut-caching-in-asp.net-mvc.aspx).

Comment: I'm suprised, so what is everyone else doing with caching childactions?

Comment: @user423649, they are not using ChildActions. Caching is **not** supported for them.

Answer (score 0):

its easy, use OutputCacheAttribute.

```
[OutputCache(Duration=60, VaryByParam="None")]
public ActionResult CacheDemo() {
  return View();
}
```

Take care, Ragims

Comment: Hi,
Look at the code in my question, i have [OutputCache(Duration = 10, VaryByParam = "none")], but it gets ignore since the action is called using renerAction,
Any other idea?

Comment: and if you try set duration to value up 30sek.?

Comment: does <%= Html.RenderAction instead <% Html.RenderAction makes any changes?

Comment: Hi,
From what i saw you cannot do
<%=HTML.RenderAction
just:
<%=HTML.Action
anyway, change the action cache to:
[OutputCache(Duration = 30, VaryByParam ="*")]
still it doesn't cache the action and the sql profiler shows the quries, maybe Darin Dimitrov was right?